# Coverity, Enumerable.Where(this ...), and IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable, idisposable

So code analysis is telling me that `Enumarble.Where(this ...)` is returning an instance of `WhereListIterator<T>`, which is (looks to be) an internal type within the .NET framework that implements `IDisposable`.

Coverity doesn't like `IDisposable`'s to go un-disposed, and is therefore suggesting I dispose of said instance. Obviously I can't dispose of the instance without doing some type checking, as `Enumerable.Where(this ...)` is said to return `IEnumerable<T>`, which does not ihnerit from `IDisposable`.

My question is this: Does .NET expect me to dispose of the `WhereListIterator<T>`, or does the iterator dispose of itself (say, after each enumeration). If I'm not expected to dispose of it, then why is the interface implemented? This leads me to a third, slightly unrelated question: If `IDisposable` was implemented explicitly, would Coverity (code analysis) still think that I should dispose of it?

Code Example:

```
var myList = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };

var evenNumbers = myList.Where(x => x % 2 == 0);

foreach(var number in evenNumbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}

if(evenNumbers is IDisposable)
{
    ((IDisposable)evenNumbers).Dispose(); // This line will be executed
}
```

Comment: The foreach loop automatically calls Dispose on your behalf; if a code analysis tool does not know that fact then you should probably use a more accurate code analysis tool. You might consider reporting it as a bug to the maintainers of the tool.

Comment: This was my thought exactly, but rather than be stubborn about it, I figured I should ask the community.

Comment: Or, you should wait for the people who produce that analysis tool to hire Eric Lippert to rewrite their stuff. This problem no longer seems to exist in Coverity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you don't need to dispose of it yourself. Note that you can demonstrate this sort of thing without any need for LINQ. In this case I believe `WhereListIterator<T>` is actually a hand-written class, but an iterator block shows something similar:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var empty = Empty();
        Console.WriteLine(empty is IDisposable); // Prints True
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> Empty()
    {
        yield break;
    }
}
```

It really implements `IDisposable` because it implements not just `IEnumerable<T>` but also `IEnumerator<T>` as an optimization - the iterable acts as the iterator as well, in the common case where you only iterate once. A `foreach` loop will implicitly dispose of an `IEnumerator<T>`, and you don't *need* to dispose of it unless you iterate anyway.

Basically, you're fine here - although it's a pity that Coverity is warning you about it. (I haven't used Coverity myself, to be honest - I don't know if there's something you can do to tweak its behaviour here.)

Answer (score 5):

if you are not using the foreach loop and using the old way to iterate

```
var v = new List<int>() { 1,2,3};
var enumerator = v.GetEnumerator();
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{

    Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
}
```

then you should call the Dispose method